# Build once deploy many with Jenkins and Github (specific branching workflow)

Tags: jenkins, build, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

Im creating Jenkins pipeline for building and deploying our app. 
I want to have the same build for the staging and production environment(buld-once-deploy-many approach).

Merging feature branch into `staging` branch would build an app for both staging and production, but it will deploy it only to `staging` bucket.

After testing, it would be good that developers merge the `staging` branch into `master` which will take the previous `staging` build and deploy it to production.

Alternative would be to have one branch, and devs would manually trigger another job on Jenkins that would deploy the build to production. 
I want to avoid devs going into jenkins and triggering build, since most of them find it intimidating, there are also some nasty vpn configuration steps they need to go through to have access to Jenkins etc.

Would this be a bad practice? Do you have any suggestions how to achieve something like this?

Thanks

Comment: You should check out multibranch pipelines.  Then based on branch name, you can make your decisions.  
stage('build and package'){
   when {
                expression { BRANCH_NAME ==~ /(master|staging|develop)/ }
            }
            steps { //do something}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a devops question than a Jenkins question, but here is my take...

I can't decide if you are saying that you would re-build from the master branch, or only use the commit to the master branch to trigger a deployment of the original staging artifact. So I'll address both.

**For this situation:**

If you build an artifact in a staging branch, and test it. Everything looks green on the tests. So you merge those changes to another branch, re-build, and deploy to production.

**The problem:** Can you be **100%** sure that there was nothing else in the master branch that is not different than what was built AND tested in staging?

You are risking the jello view anti-pattern because unknown and untested changes could sneak into your production artifact. It becomes terribly difficult to troubleshoot why it worked fine it staging, but now fails in production.

**For the second situation:**

If you are saying that you wouldn't rebuild from the master branch, then merging back to master doesn't buy you anything except a trigger to kick off a new build, because you are never generating an artifact from Master.

If you are going to to it this way, I think you could commit to a single branch, and then tag a release that is meant to go to production, then trigger off of the tag.

Either way, this seems like a strange pattern, and would be difficult to accomplish in an automated fashion in Jenkins. Somehow the newly triggered build would have to find the previously built artifact and deploy that to production.

**Possible solution:**

There are a few ways to solve this, but one of the easiest is to build once and deploy the same artifact all the way down the line, as you mentioned as an alternative option. But this would likely require some approvals or additional triggering in Jenkins.

If you don't want developers to have to touch Jenkins, then the more likely solution is to build and run your unit tests and smoke tests on the staging environment. Then when a developer wants to promote a build to production, they commit it to the master branch, where the same build is kicked off, and testing is all performed again, in addition to more advanced integration, functional, and acceptance testing. If it doesn't pass, it doesn't go to production.

Your initial tests in staging give the developer quick feedback, but don't serve as the official tests, which only run on the production build.

With a pipeline script, you could easily accomplish this with a single Jenkinsfile and single multibranch pipeline job with stages that are only run when the branch pattern matches.

```
stage ("Acceptance Testing" ) {
    when { branch "master" }
    echo "Do testing here"
}
```